# Require decorated function to accept argument matching bound `TypeVar` without narrowing to that type

Tags: python, mypy, python-decorators, python-typing, pyright

If I define my decorator like this

```py
T = TypeVar('T', bound=Event)

def register1(evtype: Type[T]) -> Callable[[Callable[[T], None]], Callable[[T], None]]:
    def decorator(handler):
        # register handler for event type
        return handler
    return decorator
```

I get a proper error if I use it on the wrong function:

```py
class A(Event):
    pass

class B(Event):
    pass

@register1(A) # Argument of type "(ev: B) -> None" cannot be assigned to parameter of type "(A) -> None"
def handler1_1(ev: B):
    pass
```

However, it does not work if I apply the decorator multiple times:

```py
@register1(A) # Argument of type "(B) -> None" cannot be assigned to parameter of type "(A) -> None"
@register1(B)
def handler1_3(ev: A|B):
    pass
```

I kind of want the decorators to build up a `Union` of allowed/required argument types.

I think `ParamSpec` is the way to solve it, but how can I use `ParamSpec` to not overwrite the argument type but also require that the argument type matches the type that is in the decorator argument?

Using `ParamSpec` does not result in any type error:

```py
P = ParamSpec("P")

def register2(evtype: Type[T]) -> Callable[[Callable[P, None]], Callable[P, None]]:
    def decorator(handler):
        # ...
        return handler
    return decorator

@register2(A) # This should be an error
def handler2_1(ev: B):
    pass
```

If I add another `TypeVar` and use a `Union` it does work for the double-decorated and even triple decorated function, but not or single decorated functions.

```py
T2 = TypeVar('T2')

def register3(evtype: Type[T]) -> Callable[[Callable[[Union[T,T2]], None]], Callable[[Union[T,T2]], None]]:
    def decorator(handler):
        # ...
        return handler
    return decorator

# Expected error:
@register3(A) # Argument of type "(ev: B) -> None" cannot be assigned to parameter of type "(A | T2@register3) -> None"
def handler3_1(ev: B):
    pass

# Wrong error:
@register3(A) # Argument of type "(ev: A) -> None" cannot be assigned to parameter of type "(A | T2@register3) -> None"
def handler3_2(ev: A):
    pass

# Works fine
@register3(A)
@register3(B)
def handler3_3(ev: A|B):
    pass
```

While writing this question, I came the solution closer and closer.
And I will provide my own solution in an Answer.

However, I'm interested if there are better ways to solve this.

Comment: Did you want something like this? https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.12&gist=503d4f09a870f18d48ea608da950337f

Comment: Kind of, but line 48 should error, because `handler4` does not accept `B` and line 56 shouldn't error, because `B()` is a valid argument for`handler2`.

Comment: Oh, you wanted the annotation to match the registered classes. I thought you wanted to union more and more callables upon registration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transported from https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/discussions/7404 --

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from typing import Any, Callable, Protocol, TypeVar, overload

T_co = TypeVar("T_co", covariant=True)

T0 = TypeVar("T0")
T1 = TypeVar('T1')

class RegisterResult(Protocol[T_co]):
    @overload
    def __call__(self, handler: Callable[[T_co | T1], None]) -> Callable[[T_co | T1], None]: ...

    @overload
    def __call__(self, handler: Callable[[T_co], None]) -> Callable[[T_co], None]: ...

def register(evtype: type[T0]) -> RegisterResult[T0]:
    def decorator(handler: Any) -> Any:
        return handler
    
    return decorator

class A: ...
class B: ...
class C: ...

@register(A)
def handle_a(ev: A): ...

handle_a(A())

@register(A)
@register(B)
# ... Should support infinite amount of @register calls
def handle_ab(ev: A|B): ... 

handle_ab(A())
handle_ab(B())

#Expected error cases because of wrong types:
@register(A)
def handle_b(ev: B): ... 
handle_a(B())
handle_ab(C())
```

Note that the code above is working with latest Pyright (v1.1.353) and may cease working in a future version based on how Pyright deals with compatibilities of overloaded functions. And it is NOT fully working with latest Mypy (v1.9.0) as I checked.

Answer (score 0):

**This is only a partial solution. It only works for the `register` side, but does not typecheck the calling side properly**

By adding the case for when the decorated function only accepts a single argument to the decorator argument using a `Union`, I don't get any unexpected errors from `pyright` anymore:

```py
def register4(evtype: Type[T]) -> Callable[[Union[Callable[[T|T2], None],Callable[[T], None]]], Callable[[T|T2], None]]:
    def decorator(handler):
        # ...
        return handler
    return decorator

#Expected errors
@register4(A) # Argument of type "(ev: B) -> None" cannot be assigned to parameter of type "((A | T2@register4) -> None) | ((A) -> None)"
def handler4_1(ev: B):
    pass

@register4(A)
def handler4_2(ev: A):
    pass

@register4(A)
@register4(B)
#@register4(C)
def handler4_3(ev: A|B|C):
    pass
```

As was pointed out in the comments:

```py
handler4_2(B())
```

does not result in an error, even though it should.

I tried to fix it by splitting the `Union` into `@overload` declarations, but that doesn't work:

```
@overload
def register4(evtype: Type[T]) -> Callable[[Callable[[T | T2], None]],Callable[[T | T2], None]]: ...


@overload
# Overload 2 for "register2" will never be used because its parameters overlap overload 1
def register4(evtype: Type[T]) -> Callable[[Callable[[T], None]], Callable[[T], None]]: ...
```

I think it ignores the second overlap, because it thinks they overlap, but we've already seen, that both cases are interpreted differently in `register3`.
And the behavior on the examples also changes if I swap the two declarations. So this might be a `pyright` bug.

This is with `pyright 1.1.352`.

Comment: I don't think `handler4_2` works. This is getting no errors: `handler4_2(B())`.